# Unable to get value of persisted state using redux-persist after the store is rehydrated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, persist

So let's say I have a Home Component which it just perform api call to fetch all homeworks from the server:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { fetchHomeWorks } from '../actions';
import HomeWorkRow from '../component/HomeWorkRow';


class Home extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchHomeWorks()
    }

    renderHomeWorks() {
        const { home_works, error, loading } = this.props;

        if(!error) {
            if(!loading){
                if(home_works.length >=1) {
                    return home_works.map(home_work => {
                        return <HomeworkRow key={uuid()} home_work={home_work} />
                    })
                }
                else
                    return <p className="pt-card col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-1 content"> No Task Yet :)</p> 
            }
            else 
                return <p>Loading...</p>
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Layout>
                { this.props.renderHomeworks() }
            </Layout>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ home_work, persist }) => {
    return {
        home_works: home_work.home_works,
        persist: 
    };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchHomeWorks })(Home);
```

on page refresh, Of course it will perform the api call because of componentDidMount() lifecycle.. Now, I want to change it and use the `persisted` data using `redux-persist` so it will avoid the api call whenever page is refreshed...

I am using the `redux-persist` library..
Here is my app component with redux persist():

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import { compose, createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import {persistStore, autoRehydrate} from 'redux-persist';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import logger from 'redux-logger';

import rootReducer from './reducers/';


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const store = createStore(rootReducer, {}, compose(applyMiddleware(thunk, logger), autoRehydrate()));
    persistStore(store);
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <div>
            <Route exact path="/" component={LoginForm} />
           // ... some routes which doesnt matter
          </div>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I know the resux persist is working because of the redux logger
[image: snapshot of redux logger]

Now, how do I get the value of the persisted state? I tried making another reducer:
`persistReducer`
    import { PERSIST } from '../actions/types';

```
export default (state = [], action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case PERSIST:
            return { ...state, persistState: action.payload }
        default:
            return state;   
    }
};
```

and adding it in `rootReducer`:

```
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form'

import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import homeWorkReducer from './userReducer';
import persistReducer from './persistReducer';

export default combineReducers({
    home_works: homeWorkReducer,
    form: formReducer,
    persist: persistReducer
});
```

and in my `Home` component, i access it using

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

    if(nextProps.persist.persistState) {
        console.log(nextProps.persist.persistState.home_works.home_works)   
    }
}
```

and getting the values correctly: [image]

so how to do it correctly?

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to analyze it. It's actually a very good question given your current setup. You clearly have redux-persist installed, possibly totally correct. I see your mapStateToProps has a colon in it. That is definitely an error in your code, not sure if that's in your project currently. It looks to me like your store should be persisted in the component as `this.props.persist` which is an object that contains the properties that would normally be on `state` inside the reducer. I feel like it is very close to working. It looks like just an issue with consuming the persisted store.

Comment: For anyone else analyzing, you will need to examine https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist

Comment: You know what, it looks like it should be available in your component as `this.props.persist.persistState`. Can you console.log that in your render method and see if it shows data? or nextProps, lol, I am exhausted on it. It looks like it should be working.

Answer (score 1):

**Side note**, but you can clean up the code a bit if you reverse the logic in your if statements:

this:

```
renderHomeWorks() {
    const { home_works, error, loading } = this.props;

    if(!error) {
        if(!loading){
            if(home_works.length >=1) {
                return home_works.map(home_work => {
                    return <HomeworkRow key={uuid()} home_work={home_work} />
                })
            }
            else
                return <p className="pt-card col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-1 content"> No Task Yet :)</p> 
        }
        else 
            return <p>Loading...</p>
    }
}
```

can become:

```
renderHomeWorks() {
    const { home_works, error, loading } = this.props;

    if (error) return <p>Loading...</p>

    if (loading || !home_works) return <p className="pt-card col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-1 content"> No Task Yet :)</p> 

    return home_works.map(home_work => <HomeworkRow key={uuid()} home_work={home_work} />)
}
```

1. You can omit the `{` and `}` for if statements that only have one expression.
2. `0` is a falsy value, so `home_works.length === 0` and `!home_works` both return true
3. You can use implicit return with fat arrow `=>` syntax if the function only returns one expression (in almost all cases)

For example, `home_works.map(() => something())` is the same as `home_works.map(() => { return something() })`. You can use JSX this way also if it only returns one JSX element (such as a div, or one component).

This code I just showed you works because as React is rendering HomeWorks, it first checks if there is an error -- if so, returns from the render function -- then, it checks if it is loading or if `home_works` is falsy -- if so, returns from the function -- and finally, it goes ahead and renders the list of homework rows.